# What is REST API for getting latest Oracle jre from oracle Community

Tags: java, docker, centos

I need to install oracle jre 8 on docker container. In docker file I am hard coding the command `wget --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u161-b12/0da788060d494f5095bf8624735fa2f1/jre-8u161-linux-x64.rpm`

The oracle community keeps chainging the jre version and updates the jre download website.
Is there any installer command in CentOS or any REST api that gives the above URL.

Comment: Couldn't you use an image that already has Java 8 (e.g `FROM anapsix/alpine-java:8` ) ?

Comment: But I need to install CentOS image

Comment: You may get both : https://hub.docker.com/r/webdizz/centos-java8/

Answer (score 2):

```
     wget -q --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie"  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u181-b13/96a7b8442fe848ef90c96a2fad6ed6d1/jre-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

OR

```
    wget -q --no-check-certificate --no-cookies --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie"  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u181-b13/96a7b8442fe848ef90c96a2fad6ed6d1/jre-8u181-linux-x64.rpm
```

The above command worked for me please use according to your requiremnt ...please try this and let me know the results and if this should be updated.